# Avoiding the GOTO paradigm in Fortran FORMAT when reading/writing

Tags: fortran, format, goto

At the university, the professor teaching us Fortran, gave us the following code:

```
     program example
     integer year, month, day, inst, kind, ozone
     real time
     open(unit=1,file='C:\261.dat')
     read(1,1000) year, month, day, inst, kind, ozone, time
     close(1)  
1000 format(i4,1x,i2,1x,i2,1x,i1,1x,i1,1x,i3,1x,f8.3)
     end
```

In this code, the line indexed with 1000 specifies the particular input format. Isn't it something like a GOTO logic? And if yes, what's the most appropriate way to avoid it, in the context of Fortran?

Comment: It's nothing like a `GO TO`: there's no "jump" in execution control in referencing that line, but it's simply using a definition from somewhere else - much as using a variable defined elsewhere isn't like a `GO TO`. Are you thinking about the flow control that comes from `err=100` in a read statement?

Comment: It's not a `goto` as @francescalus says, but I agree the label is ugly, as is defining part of the statement elsewhere. Instead of the line label you can just  have the format as a character variable or constant - which I much prefer, and is ultimately more flexible.

Comment: @IanBush, I've always been fascinated by people who hate `format` statements ;). I agree that they have limitations and other ways are sometimes better, but `read(1,fmt_char)` "defin[es] part of the statement elsewhere" just as much as `read(1,1000)`.

Comment: Remember that GOTO isn't  bad just because there is some label used there. It is bad because it jumps somewhere without some easy to see structure for going back or going further. Nothing like that appears here. We exactly know and easily see what happens next.

Comment: @francescalus To be honest I rarely use the character variable form (except when needed) - The vast majority are character constant, which has all you need in one compact form

Comment: I concur, my main problem with FORMAT is that one must look for the declaration somewhere else that can most often just included in the statement as a constant. I even prefer some repetition, if it is trivial.

Comment: Hopefully the professor told you to always use `implicit none` and not to use the lower unit numbers (here `1`) as you might be in a larger program in for some nice surprises.

Comment: Within the paradigm of structured and procedural programming, the usage of labels to reference formats is practical from a development-maintenance perspective. Imagine you have an input file with 10 different date-times and your output contains 100 date-times. When using the label, you only need to update a single `FORMAT` statement to modify all input-output date-times in a single go. This is something you would do within the class if you use object-oriented programming.

Comment: @IanBush you are correct that using strings makes sense, but then again. Even the content of these character variables could be in other locations, even other files. Also, this makes the format computationally and therefore a bit slower in execution time (however, this is purely academic as this does not matter too much with current systems). I believe the usage of character variables, vs labels vs format-strings all depends on the programming style.

Comment: @albert could you please elaborate on the `implicit none` suggestion?

Comment: @kvantour If I understand you correctly in such a case I would use a `character` symbolic constant (a.k.a. a `parameter`)  which gives the same benefits, plus you can call it something meaningful. But yes it is ultimately style - and I think labels are just plain ugly.

Comment: By default the variables in Fortran get a default type (variables starting with a-h and o-z will be reals variables starting with i..n will be integers. I.e. An IMPLICIT NONE
statement can indicate that no implicit typing rules are to apply in a particular scoping unit (subroutine, function etc.), please consult a Fortran learning book or the Fortran standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a formatted data transfer statement there are three ways to specify the format to use (Fortran 2018 R1215):

- referencing a labelled FORMAT statement
- using a (default) character expression
- with a `*` (for list-directed formatting)

For example (using a PRINT statement for clarity):

```
1000 FORMAT (I0)

print 1000, 1     ! Pointing to a FORMAT statement
print '(I0)', 1   ! Literal constant: one form of a character expression
print *, 1        ! List-directed formatting

end
```

In none of these is the format specification functionally like a GO TO statement.

A GO TO statement changes the flow of execution whereas in the format specification execution remains at the data transfer statement, and then continues to the next statement.

Specifying a label for the format doesn't transfer execution control to that statement, it simply says "use the format given by the statement 1000". This is conceptually like how

```
character(*), parameter :: CHAR_FMT='(I0)'
print CHAR_FMT, 1
end
```

says "use the character object `CHAR_FMT` (which is declared/defined elsewhere)" as the format.

You'll find may objections to FORMAT statements and (reasonable) suggestions for alternatives, but no objection to using a FORMAT statement is based on "like a GO TO". (And, of course, GO TO statements are not inherently evil.)

---

Format specifications can be contrasted with the `err=` and `end=` and `eor=` specifiers: these functionally are like GO TO statements:

```
1 read(unit, fmt, err=10, end=20, eor=20) x
...
! COME FROM 1
20 continue
...

return
! COME FROM 1
10 ERROR STOP "Error in the read"
```

Such jump-like flow can be alternatively managed with IOSTAT control:

```
read(unit, fmt, iostat=iostat) x
if (iostat...) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using format labels by instead using [format strings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/c40004a77a7a/index.html), as

```
program example
  integer year, month, day, inst, kind, ozone
  real time
  
  open(unit=1,file='C:\261.dat')
  read(1,'(i4,1x,i2,1x,i2,1x,i1,1x,i1,1x,i3,1x,f8.3)') year, month, day, inst, kind, ozone, time
  close(1)
end
```

you can treat the format string as a regular `character` variable, as

```
program example
  integer year, month, day, inst, kind, ozone
  real time
  character(42) :: format
  
  open(unit=1,file='C:\261.dat')
  format = '(i4,1x,i2,1x,i2,1x,i1,1x,i1,1x,i3,1x,f8.3)'
  read(1,format) year, month, day, inst, kind, ozone, time
  close(1)
end
```

This allows you to pass formats around your code just like any other variable, and also allows you to generate and modify formats at runtime.

Comment: I think it worthwhile giving an example where the format is a character constant as in practice (I think) that is the most usual and common form